# Proper Unit Testing Philosophy

Tags: database, unit-testing

What would be the proper thing to do for each case?

1: Context: Testing a function that creates a database as well as generating metadata for that database

Question: Normally unit test cases are supposed to be independent, but if we want to make sure the function raises an exception when trying to make a duplicate database, would it be acceptable to have ordered test cases where the first one tests if the function works, and the second one tests if it fails when calling it again?

2: Most of the other functions require a database and metadata. Would it be better to call the previous functions in the set up of each test suite to create the database and metadata, or would it be better to hard code the required information in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Normally unit test cases are supposed to be independent, but if we want to make sure the function raises an exception when trying to make a duplicate database, would it be acceptable to have ordered test cases where the first one tests if the function works, and the second one tests if it fails when calling it again?**

No, ordered tests are bad.  There's nothing stopping you from having a test call another method that happens to be a test though:

```
@Test
public void createDataBase(){
  ...
}

@Test
public void creatingDuplicateDatabaseShouldFail(){
   createDataBase();
   try{
      //call create again should fail
      //could also use ExpectedException Rule here
      createDataBase();
      fail(...);
   }catch(...){ 
    ...
   }
}
```

**Most of the other functions require a database and metadata. Would it be better to call the previous functions in the set up of each test suite to create the database and metadata, or would it be better to hard code the required information in the database?**

If you use a database testing framework like DbUnit or something similar, it can reuse the same db setup over and over again in each test.

Comment: Ordered tests are good if your test execution is based on speed and scope. For example execute unit tests first and then if all passes execute integration tests.

Comment: That's not the same "ordered" as what the OP is asking about.  In this case ordered means"execute this unit test before that one".  Separating unit tests and integration tests (or a similar category based on speed) is fine and often beneficial, but the execution order of the  tests in each of those groups should not matter

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are ordered tests inherently worse than the above solution of using one test to run another test twice?

Comment: Executing Ordered Tests will result in test results being non-repeatable if System Under Test's state is not wiped. Do NOT depend on tests to setup preconditions for other tests. It will be a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Your automated test should model the following:

1. Setup
2. Exercise (SUT)
3. Verify
4. Teardown

In addition, each test should be as concise as possible and only expose the details that are being tested. All other infrastructure that is required to execute the test should be abstracted away so that the test method serves as documention that only exposes the inputs that are being tested in regards to what you want to verify for that particular test.

Each test should strive to start from a clean slate so that the test can be repeated with the same results each time regardless of the results of prior tests that have been executed.

I typically execute a test-setup and a test-cleanup method for each integration test or any test that depends on singletons that maintain state for the System-Under-Test and need to have it's state wiped.